# Is there anyway to import bulk data through the CloudKit Dashboard?

Tags: json, cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

I see how to create record types and add records one at a time in the CloudKit dashboard. I want to try adding a few hundred records for testing. Is there any way to import CSV or JSON files into dashboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is not. You have to create an import mechanism in your app. (Or you could use the CloudKit api from another app/website)

Comment: the import is rate and size limited so even with a batch upload to load up a few million records it takes years. while the op only has a few hundred so this will work for him. I feel like the only real way to do a larger number is to move away from CloudKit to something like aws or google cloud

Answer (score 0):

On one hand you can only create records one at a time in the CloudKit dashboard.

On the other hand, you **can** import a CSV or JSON file as a CKAsset field in each record. Then your app can fetch that CKRecord and parse the CKAsset field.